# Is Questdb compatible with Grafana 8?

Tags: questdb

I've seen some questions, plus an integration guide for Grafana with Questdb, and I'm curious if it supports Grafana 8, including real-time streaming over websocket. Is there a list of features that are supported in this version. I'm using QuestDB 6.0.3 which is the current latest, running it via Docker.

Answer (score 0):

QuestDB doesn't support websockets. The integration with grafana is achieved by using the PostgreSQL plugin and creating a datasource that connects to your QuestDB instance